# Display variable inside my render React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was trying to display data from a fetch function to my render app in react native.

I was able to get the data from my fetch but i am not able to display it on the app..

this is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';


export default function App() {

const fetchDatos = async () => {
    return fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/consulta').then(response => {
      return response.json();
  })
  .then(responseJson => {
    var Nombre = responseJson.Participante.InfoParticipante['@attributes'].Nombre;
  });
}

  return (
    <View>
    <Button 
      title='press me'
      onPress={fetchDatos}
    />
    <Text>{Nombre}</Text>
    </View>
  );

}
```

As you can see in the code above I get the data stored in the var ''Nombre'' and I am trying the display it in the app but it's telling me `Uncaught ReferenceError: Nombre is not defined`

Does anyone know how to fix this, I would appreciate it a lot!

Comment: are you using hooks or class components?

Comment: `Nombre` is out of scope for one..

Comment: scope of `var Nombre` is within the `fetchDatos` funciton. you need to use state variable for that

Comment: Use this - https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data - the answers below don't really cover all cases so you will most likely run into issues.

Comment: Alright @goto1 I will read the guide thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';


export default function App() {

const [nombre,setNombre]=useState()
const fetchDatos = () => {
    return fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/consulta').then(response => {
      return response.json();
  })
  .then(responseJson => {
    setNombre(responseJson.Participante.InfoParticipante['@attributes'].Nombre);
  });
}

  return (
    <View>
    <Button 
      title='press me'
      onPress={fetchDatos}
    />
    <Text>{nombre}</Text>
    </View>
  );

}
```

Comment: GREAT! this worked @Prakash Reddy Potlapadu :D, just needed to fix this line:
  const [nombre,setNombre]= React.useState('');

Comment: @BetolGM I imported `useState ` in the first line